# Add a hyperlink to a Div Class

Tags: html

I'm a graphic design student, I am trying to do my portfolio, however not sure how to add a hyperlink to an icon that appears when you hover your mouse over a portfolio item. The item in code reads as div class="hoverIconChain"

```
<div class="portfolio-item html android">
  <a href="portfolio-item-detail-page.html" class="animatedImage3">
    <img src="images/portfolio02.jpg" alt="Portfolio 02">
    <div class="hoverWrapperBg"></div>
    <div class="hoverWrapper">
      <div class="hoverIconChain"></div>
      <div class="hoverIconHeart"></div>
      <div class="hoverBottom">
        <div class="hoverBottomText">Real Gamers Network</div>
        <div class="hoverBottomLike"> 63 </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the ending a tag from the bottom of your code, and move it after image.

```
<a href="portfolio-item-detail-page.html" class="animatedImage3">
  <img src="images/portfolio02.jpg" alt="Portfolio 02">
</a>
```

To add a hyperlink to a div, just do it like this.

```
<a href="http://google.com">
  <div class="hoverIconChain"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much i wanted to give you rep but it wouldn't allow me because i am new. Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question I really appreciate it

Comment: I think that a block element inside an inline element is not valid html markup, you should put the anchor tag inside the div and change the display style of the anchor to block and width=height=100%

Comment: Yeah i just tried it and it spazed out and had spaces between the portfolio images lol, could you post an example for me please arieljuod i got most of what your saying but i have no idea how to change the display style ?